# Restoring Typus plugin after changing DB Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scaffolding, admin-interface

I installed Typus plugin (http://intraducibles.com/projects/typus) for my app and I love it. But along the development of the app I frequently do migrations and change the DB Schema and relationships, and then the plugin fails. Is there a way to re-generate the plugin with the new schema? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simply entering

```
rails generate typus
```

again will set things right.

Answer (score 0):

Only removing and reinstalling Typus at the end of the development cycle.